# How to obtain overlapping patterns with Python finditer?

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, fasta

I'm using a python script that is searching for a pattern in a fasta file. It is working very well but it does not return overlapping strings. Unfortunately, I'm interested in potential overlapping strings. Since I'm not a programmer (I'm just trying to learn Python), I was wondering if someone could modify the script in order to find overlapping strings. I think that the regex module could do it but I tried to install it on my computer (Windows) without succes. I got this:

```
C:\Python33>regex-2014.02.19>python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
runnning built_ext
building'_regex' extension
error:Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

For me it would be easier to work with a modified script. So here is my script:

```
import re
import sys

psq_re_f= re.compile('G{3,}.{1,7}?G{3,}.{1,7}?G{3,}.{1,7}?G{3,}') #((?<=G)[^G]|(?<!G).)
psq_re_r= re.compile('C{3,}.{1,7}?C{3,}.{1,7}?C{3,}.{1,7}?C{3,}') #((?<=C)[^C]|(?<!C).)


filename = input('Enter the name of the input fasta file: ')
ref_seq_fh = open(filename)

outputfileg = open("strelkaindels_quadg.txt",'wt')
outputfilec = open("strelkaindels_quadc.txt",'wt')

outputfileg.write('#\tID\tEntry Length\tStart\tEnd\tLength\tStrand\tSequence\n')
outputfilec.write('#\tID\tEntry Length\tStart\tEnd\tLength\tStrand\tSequence\n')

count = 0
ref_seq = []
line = (ref_seq_fh.readline()).strip()
chr = re.sub('^>', '', line)
chr1 = chr.split (":")
#line = (ref_seq_fh.readline()).strip()
while True:
    while line.startswith('>') is False:
        ref_seq.append(line)
        line = (ref_seq_fh.readline()).strip()
        if line == '':
            break
    ref_seq = ''.join(ref_seq)
    for m in re.finditer(psq_re_f, ref_seq):
        count=count+1
        outputfileg.write('%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s' %(count, chr1[0], len(ref_seq), m.start(), m.end(), len(m.group(0)), '+', m.group(0))+'\n')
    for m in re.finditer(psq_re_r, ref_seq):
        count=count+1
        outputfilec.write('%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s' %(count, chr1[0], len(ref_seq), m.start(), m.end(), len(m.group(0)), '-', m.group(0))+'\n')
    chr = re.sub('^>', '', line)
    chr1 = chr.split (":")
    ref_seq = []
    line= (ref_seq_fh.readline()).strip()
    if line == '':
        break


outputfileg.close()
outputfilec.close()
```

Finally an example of fasta file (text-based format for representing nucleotide sequences) widely used in biology:

```
>id_1
agatagatgatagatatagagagcgcgctagatcgatcgatcgagtcgatcgcgcggggggcccctctctctctatagggacatacga
>id_2
agacatcagatacagagatatttacataacaagagatacag
>id_3
cgctctagctcctcctctcgcgtagctagctctctctaacatgattagaattcagatcgatcgatcgatggttttttttctctct
and so on...
```

For example, let's imagine the following sequence:

```
GGGTGGGTGGGCGGGAGGG
```

The script will return only this string:

```
GGGTGGGTGGGCGGG
```

But I would like to also get that one too:

```
GGGTGGGCGGGAGGG
```

Comment: I don't think RegEx can support matching overlapping patterns.

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're trying to solve? It sounds like you're trying to match each string (sequence) to the sequence that has the most overlap. Does the overlap have to occur at the ends? Does gagttca overlap with ccagttgg (because they share agtt), or is that not allowed?

At first glance, it sounds like you have an instance of the [Longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem), but if you post more information about your goals we can help you more easily.

Comment: @bgschiller I have edited my question (look at the end, I added an example). Hope it is clearer now... Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a positive looakehead:

```
(?=(G{3,}.{1,7}?G{3,}.{1,7}?G{3,}.{1,7}?G{3,}))
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY5tZ3)

And in your code, you will have to change your groups to `.group(1)` but `m.end()` will be the same as `m.start()`, so you might work around it a bit, maybe my using `len()`:

```
for m in re.finditer(psq_re_f, ref_seq):
    count=count+1
    outputfileg.write('%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s' % (count,
                      chr1[0], len(ref_seq), m.start(),
                      m.start() + len(m.group(1)), len(m.group(1)),
                      '+',m.group(1))+'\n')
```

Comment: I think the modifications you suggested regarding the pattern matching (and overlaps) could work well but I'm not able to get any prints in my output file... Since there is more than 1 match, I was wondering if the problem could originate from the string of the write method.

Comment: @Frank_B Are the sequences in your files lowercase? If so, you might want to make your regex case insensitive: `psq_re_f= re.compile(r'(?=(G{3,}.{1,7}?G{3,}.{1,7}?G{3,}.{1,7}?G{3,}))', re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: @Frank_B Hmm, I just tested the sequences of `id_1` through `id_3` and none of them match the pattern you're looking for? Are you sure they should match?

Comment: The fasta file example (i.e id 1-3) was only an example of fasta file to help understanding what is a fasta file for people outside of biosiences. I just type random sequence and there are no prossible matches in this example... The only good example to test the pattern is this one: GGGTGGGTGGGCGGGAGGG. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Frank_B Okay, I just ran the code and it's working fine for me. With the single sequence, the file `strelkaindels_quadg.txt` gets two lines. Just in case, here's the full code: [link](http://pastebin.com/eDnVKgAZ)

Comment: In your regex101 demo link above, you add a g modifier to the pattern. I added it also to my script. But if I dont't, I got 2 lines in strelkaindels.txt file, and the idle returned me <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000337DB70>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000003426E40>. So it seems to work now. How to get rid of those lines returned by the idle?

Comment: @Frank_B No, you use it just like in the link I gave above. Regex101 was primarily based off PCRE regex, but in python, you use `re.findall` or `re.finditer` likein your current code. Also, what do you mean by the idle? Getting 'match object' means that you did not put `.group(1)` to the matches.

Comment: the IDLE is found in the start menu, (Stands for Integrated Development Environment). This is where I send my commands. I got two lines after running the script <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000320AEB8>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000320AB70>. But I also got my two lines in the ouput file. So it is working! I'm very happy. The only concern is the two lines that I got in the IDLE. It's the first time I see these characters.

Comment: @Frank_B Those are what you see when you print match objects. As such, they are not very useful (AFAIK), but you can tap into them using `.group()`, `.start()` and such. The docs about the re module has more details about what you can use on the object. Feel free to mark my answer as accepted :)